# open a facebook using iframe in phonegap

Tags: ios5, cordova

I am new to develop phone gap applications I have Link button for Facebook  in app when click on it should open within i frame fore this I have use following code it wont open Facebook

```
<iframe width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0"
     marginwidth="0" src="http://www.facebook.com"></iframe>
```

and also i tried http://m.facebook.com.

Answer (score 0):

If you use xCode you should add www.facebook.com to your external hosts whitelist. It's in Cordova.plist/phonegap.plist file.

Comment: i already added *facebook.com to the plist, and when i run his i get the error in console -'Failed to load webpage with error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -999.)'